# Does Blender run on ARM-based processors

Tags: gpu

I am using Blender on a Mac application called 'Parallels' which is a Windows computer for the Mac (https://www.parallels.com). However, Blender fails to start when using the Parallels app. I tried this both on 2 Macs: an M1 Mac Studio and an Intel MacBook Pro 2017. Both gave me the same results.

I reached out to their support page, and they wanted me to check whether Blender works on ARM-based processors or not.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Blender has had an official Apple ARM port since a year ago (April 2021) and you can find [daily builds](https://builder.blender.org/download/daily/) and [official releases](https://www.blender.org/download/) on the Foundation's web site; as well as various Linux arm packages on other sites.

However, if you're having trouble with parallels on both Intel and Arm, it sounds like there's a problem with parallels.  You would need to go to the [Parallels forum](https://forum.parallels.com/) to find out more; as we're not likely to have answers here.